# struct comparator constructor vs operator () in c++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, operator-overloading, comparator

I have this code:

```
struct PointComparator
{
   explicit PointComparator(const Point& lowest)
      : m_lowest(lowest)
   {}
   
   bool operator()(const Point& a, const Point& b)
   {
      std::cout << m_lowest[0] << std::endl;
      return; // TODO
   }

private:
   Point m_lowest;
};

// in another function:
Point lowestPoint;  // (get this from somewhere)
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), PointComparator(lowestPoint));
```

I'm just confused on the explicit keyword. When I do a normal sort, I would call something like `sort(sort(points.begin(), points.end(), compar())`, and compar() points to the `bool operator()(const Point& a, const Point& b)` function, but now `PointComparator(lowestPoint)` refers to the constructor so how does it still work?

Comment: It doesn't "refer to the constructor", it's just constructing an anonymous object, which happens to use the single-argument constructor you wrote. What specifically is confusing about that? Why do you think `explicit` makes it more confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I do a normal sort, I would call something like `sort(sort(points.begin(), points.end(), compar())`, and `compar()` points to the `bool operator()(const Point& a, const Point& b)` function, [...]

Actually, no. The third parameter passed to `sort` is a comparator. It can be a function object that has a `operator()`. You do not pass its `operator()` to the algorithm.

When you write:

```
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), PointComparator(lowestPoint));
```

this is more or less the same as

```
PointComparator compare(lowestPoint);
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), compare);
```

`PointComparator(lowestPoint)` is calling the constructor. The created object is passed to `sort` and only internally `sort` calls the `operator()`.

The `explicit` here only means that implicit conversions from `Point` to `PointComparator` are blocked. It does not really have an effect on your code.

Answer (score 1):

> When I do a normal sort, I would call something like sort(sort(points.begin(), points.end(), compar()), and compar() points to the bool operator()(const Point& a, const Point& b) function

No it doesn't. `compar()` is syntax for a temporary object that is value initialised.

> but now PointComparator(lowestPoint) refers to the constructor so how does it still work?

The arguments that you pass into the constructor affect which constructor is called. In the `compar()` case, the default constructor is used, and in the `PointComparator(lowestPoint)`, the converting constructor is used. It works because `PointComparator` has a converting constructor of appropriate type.

> I'm just confused on the explicit keyword.

It means that the constructor cannot be used in an implicit conversion. It prevents following from working: `std::sort(b, e, lowestPoint);`. Avoiding implicit converting constructors is often recommended.